# Is there a way to save the order of data loaded from SQLiteDatabase?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-sqlite

I loaded the data stored in SQLiteDatabase and put it into RecyclerView. RecyclerView applied ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback to enable `onMove()`. When I change the order of vertically listed items, I want to save them in SQLiteDatabase in the same order.

#### MainActivity.kt

```
val simpleItemTouchCallback = object : ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(ItemTouchHelper.UP or ItemTouchHelper.DOWN, 0) {
    override fun onMove(recyclerView: RecyclerView, source: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder): Boolean {
        adapter.swapItems(source.adapterPosition, target.adapterPosition)
        return true
    }

    override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
        return
    }
}

val itemTouchHelper = ItemTouchHelper(simpleItemTouchCallback)
itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recycler)
```

#### MyAdapter.kt

```
fun swapItems(from: Int, to: Int) {
    if (from < to) {
        for (i in from until to) {
            arr[i + 1] = arr[i]
            arr[i] = arr[i + 1]
        }
    } else {
        for (i in from..to + 1) {
            arr[i - 1] = arr[i]
            arr[i] = arr[i - 1]
        }
    }
    notifyItemMoved(from, to)
    // TODO : From here, am I accessing the SQLiteDatabase and changing the order?
}
```

Items shown in RecyclerView change their order when `onMove()` is executed, but the order is not saved.

Comment: Database is not ordered. If you want to keep an display user order, you gonna have somehow to save this order. Add a field to your database representing your the order. Then just sort your query when you get the data with this field. And of course update it when the user change it. Don't use continuous index for the order. Give you some reserve if you need to insert a new between two existing.

Answer (score 1):

My thoughts:

1. add a special field (for instance named "view_order") in your DB entity.
2. update that field for all related entities in the DB each time than the view order will be changed.
3. don't update the DB in the main thread.
4. use [Room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room) and [RxKotlin](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxKotlin) (the first found example [here](https://medium.com/better-programming/a-detailed-guide-on-room-database-with-kotlin-rx-mvvm-ea982e9c5abe)). That approach help you fix the 3d issue above and is more flexible.